# JSDoc for new component bindings

Tags: angularjs, phpstorm, webstorm, jsdoc, angularjs-components

How to write jsdoc for `bindings.input` so that I receive type hinting in PhpStorm? I have tried the following jsdoc that I usually annotate my variables with but it ain't working.

```
angular.component('Card', {
            controller : [
                CardController
            ],
            bindings   : {
                /** @type {MyType} */
                /** @param {MyType} input */
                input: '<'
            }
        });
```

I know that in controller function I can reassign the variable but it smells:

```
/** @type {MyType} */
this.annotatedInput = this.input
```

Answer (score 0):

This works sometimes     `/** @type {MyType} */`. I can't think of why **sometimes** only.